# Is there any .NET dll around that does GIMP, or some other image program job?

Tags: .net, image-processing, graphics32

I would like to know if there is any dll that I could use to import into my C# project to handle images. 
What I am expecting to do is:

1. Increase/Decrease brigth, exposure
2. Put two photos at the same position and use the "multiply" functionality like photoshop does.
3. Scale and resize

As far as I got into it, I've found gimp#, which is not what I expected because it suits only for GIMP plugins. Digging a bit more, I found Graphics32.

Graphics32 is exactly what I need in terms of functionality, but it is not made for .NET

I'm not sure if it is possible to compile the Graphics32 code and use it in C# someway (I was thinking about it)

Comment: That's like asking if a dll can _do Photoshop_. You could always just learn GDI+ and use [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick is something I have used before:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

the .NET API's can be found on this page:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php